# Core data not displaying sqlite file data correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

The data in my sqlite table is not being displayed correctly, instead the default value I set in the core-data model is showing.

I added a new field in my sqlite table and updated my core data model. The attribute has the same name and data type as the field I just added in the sqlite file.

When I added the new core-data attribute I made sure to go add new data model version and then set that version.

I also made sure to reset the simulator and cleaned all targets in xcode.

I'm not getting any errors, it's just that I can't get the data to match up.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not mess with Core Data's sqlite database directly. Quoth [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW3):

> **Important:** Although Core Data supports SQLite as one of its persistent store types, Core Data cannot manage any arbitrary SQLite database. In order to use a SQLite database, Core Data must create and manage the database itself.

The correct way to do things is to update the Core Data model, follow the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399), and let Core Data handle updating the SQLite database itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What if I need to add data to the sqlite table?

Comment: Create an NSManagedObject and save it. Anomie is right - attempting to manipulate the sqllite store directly will bring you naught but misery.

Comment: Forget that Core Data is using an SQLite database. Ask instead "What if I need to add data to Core Data?", and then research that question.